# HTTPS : Curl failed with getaddrinfo error

Tags: curl

After this command : `curl -X POST -v -H "access_token":"password"  https://dns.com/query?start=2020-12-01&end=2021-01-01`

I getting this error :

```
* getaddrinfo(3) failed for dns.com:443
* Couldn't resolve host 'dns.com'
* Closing connection #0
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'dns.com'

[1] + Done (6)             curl -X POST -v -H "access_token":"pass
```

I don't know where is the problem ... Any idea ?

Comment: can you ping `dns.com`? Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It's solved.
The solution : `curl -X POST -v -H "access_token":"password"  "https://dns.com/query?start=2020-12-01&end=2021-01-01"`

It is necessary to surround the url with quotation marks.